# cannot convert from 'SDL_Surface' to 'SDL_Surface MainMenu::*'

Tags: c++, class, pointers, sdl

**Situation:** I'm attempting to have a `load_image` method within the `MainMenu` class so in my main class I can call the `load_image` method while in the main menu.

**Problem:** Within the `load_image` method, I'm getting the Error:

> error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'SDL_Surface' to
>   'SDL_Surface MainMenu::*'

This is occurring on line 47, underlining "optimizedImage" in red.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef MAINMENU_H
#define MAINMENU_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

using namespace std;

class MainMenu
{
    private:
        string menuOption[3];
        string background;
        string img1;
        string img2;
        string img3;
        SDL_Surface *screen;
        SDL_Surface *bkgrnd;
        SDL_Surface *item;

public:

    MainMenu(SDL_Surface *screen, string bgImg, string optionImg1, string optionImg2, string optionImg3) 
        : background(bgImg), img1(optionImg1), img2(optionImg2), img3(optionImg3)
    {

    }

    ~MainMenu();
    SDL_Surface  *load_image(string filename);
    void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination);
    bool load_files();
    void Draw();
};
#endif
```

Here is the .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MainMenu.h"
#include "glut.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

MainMenu::~MainMenu()
{
}


SDL_Surface  MainMenu::*load_image(string filename)
{
//Temporary storage for the image tgat loaded
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;

    //The optimized image that will be used
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    //Load the image
    loadedImage = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());

    //If nothing went wrong in loading the image
    if (loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        //Create an optimized image
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);

        //Free the old image
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);

        //if the image was optimized just fine
        if (optimizedImage != NULL)
        {
            //Map the color key
            Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB( optimizedImage->format,0,0xFF,0xFF);
            //Set all pixels of color R 0, G 0xFF, B 0xFF to be transparent
            SDL_SetColorKey(optimizedImage, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, colorkey);
        }
        return optimizedImage;
    }
    return optimizedImage;
}

void MainMenu::apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;
    //Give the offsets to the rectangle
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, &offset);
}

bool MainMenu::load_files()
{
    //Load images
    item = load_image(img1);
    bkgrnd = load_image(background);
    if (item == NULL || bkgrnd == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void MainMenu::Draw()
{
    apply_surface(0, 0, bkgrnd, screen);
    apply_surface(320, 0, bkgrnd, screen ); 
    apply_surface(0, 240, bkgrnd, screen ); 
    apply_surface(320, 240, bkgrnd, screen );

    apply_surface(180, 140, item, screen ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cpp file, change this:

```
SDL_Surface  MainMenu::*load_image(string filename)
```

To this:

```
SDL_Surface* MainMenu::load_image(string filename)
```

The return type of the function is `SDL_Surface*`, not `SDL_Surface`

Comment: @TimOgunmakin It's common courtesy to accept answers (the little check mark button on the left side) to both move your question out of the unanswered category on the site and to give the answer-er a little sumthin' for their help. So, y'should do it.